# OpenVPN idle bandwidth usage on dd-wrt

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt, bandwidth

Does anyone know the approximate idle bandwidth and data usage (both upload and download) required to maintain an openvpn connection (keepalive) between two routers running ddwrt?

I'm trying to factor in both usage and idle overhead to determine if our cellular connection will sustain 24x7 openvpn connection without incurring overages.

Thanks!